# Get created time using post_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find the creation time of posts that I'm tagged in or in where I tagged someone else.

```sql
SELECT post_id
FROM   stream_tag
WHERE  actor_id=me()
OR     target_id=me()
```

So I thought it would be an easy query from the stream table once I get all of the relevant post ids-

```sql
SELECT created_time
FROM   stream
WHERE  post_id
IN ^
```

But this just returns an empty dataset. If I click on one of the `postID` objects I can see the info I want, but I don't want to have to hit up the graph API individually for each of these ids. I think there has to be an easy way to do this with `FQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. This happened to be a problem with how far the stream went back. I was trying to grab data that simply isn't kept in the stream anymore. My hack to fix this was to query the post_id using the graph API-

```
FB.api('/post_id','get', function(response){
     var time= response.updated_time;
})
```